# Length of an email list in sent mail

Tags: email

I want to send an email to a large list, using Mac Mail. How many email addresses can I have in To: or cc: or bcc:? I recall there is a limit.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there is a hard limit in Mail for the number of recipients in any of the particular fields. The larger obstacle may be your mail service blocking the message because of the number of recipients: their spam filters tend to flag messages as spam when the number of recipients goes over a certain number.

What you can try - and I have had this work - is to use an Address Group. Put the contacts you are sending to in a Group in your Address Book, then enter then name of the Group in the `To:` field. It masquerades the email addresses to the recipients and may get it past the spam filters.

Comment: Technically there is no difference between adding all addresses manually to a mail or using an Address Group. In the later case Apple Mail replaces the group with the individual addresses before handing the mail to the mail server.